# SAS ods html generates additional html code

Tags: html, sas, sas-ods

I use ods html to output HTML code from SAS to body=_webout. SAS version is 9.4.
I would like to output a HTML table, but SAS generates automatically an additional table around the output of each ods html statement.
For example this is my SAS code:

```
ods html text="<table id='test'>";
```

And this is the generated HTML code:

```
<table width="100%" style=" border: 0px solid #000000; border-spacing: 0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rules="none" frame="void">
   <tr>
      <td class="l usertext">**<table id='test'>**</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Is there an option to suppress the additional code from printing by SAS? With SAS 9.2 and the same code there was not such an effect.

Comment: If the behaviour of code changes between versions you should contact tech support.  My guess in this case, its to allow more structured output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess SAS does it that way to ensure consistent formatting between ODS html outputs.

One workaround that we use to make sure that we get just what we want and nothing more is to simply use a data step in cases like this.  The datastep can write to the reserved filename _webout as long as it's running as part of a web request:

```
data _null_;
  file _webout;
  put "<table id='test'>";
run;
```

When writing to `_webout` like this there is no need for an `ODS html` statement.

Comment: I would say more accurately that SAS is doing exactly what it's being asked to: opens the ODS HTML destination, puts some text in it.  Nothing in the OP's question's code suggests SAS thinks it's being asked to output HTML.  I think you're specifically right in that writing directly to _WEBOUT without the ODS HTML is correct, but assumes the OP isn't trying to put a table out (ie, eventually include a PROC MEANS or somesuch, which I don't think (?) you can easily do through the datastep interface without more complexity (though this is not my area really).)

Comment: @Joe Yes it definitely gets more complicated to output say an entire `<table>` from a datastep. Without additional info from the OP there wasn't much more direction I could provide though.  Unless you really need a custom appearance that can't be satisfied simply by changing CSS styles, using ODS html is usually sufficient.